# Cannot find symbol class MessageRVAdapter

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, cannot-find-symbol

I do have a MessageRVAdapter in my project directory but I don't know why my app isn't finding this class.
I get the following problem in MainActivity.java within app\src\main\java\com\example\chatbot:

```
cannot find symbol
    private MessageRVAdapter messageRVAdapter;
            ^
  symbol:   class MessageRVAdapter
  location: class MainActivity
```

---

Here is my code:

```
// creating a variable for array list and adapter class.
private ArrayList<com.example.chatbot.MessageModal> messageModalArrayList;
private MessageRVAdapter messageRVAdapter;
```

---

Here is what my directory looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPAMe.jpg

Comment: First look if there is an `import`. Second is `MessageRVAdapter` in the right package ? Third let Android Studio find the import for you.

Comment: I figured it out!! For some reason it had MessageRVAdapter down as private but it should have been public in the code within MainActivity.java.